# linux shell process text

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a string below

> Properties | Account Property | Actions Property | Anniversary
>   Property | Application Property | AssistantName Property |
>   AssistantDNA Property | LabDNA....

and from a linux shell would like to find a command to process it to below format. I want to only show words that have DNA in them. The point for me here is seeing how to do this from a prompt.

```
AssistantDNA
LabDNA
```

Comment: Your question isn't understandable for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
egrep -oi '[^ ]*dna[^ ]*' file
```

Comment: thanks! I think it's working but i'm not getting the full word, only dna shows up in the list

Comment: Fixed, forgot to negate the brackets.

Comment: You don't need to escape the spaces inside bracket expressions.

Comment: In fact, the backslash is taken literally inside brackets.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` alternative:

```
awk -v RS='|' '/DNA/'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "Properties | Account Property | Actions Property | Anniversary Property | Application Property | AssistantName Property | AssistantDNA Property | LabDNA" | tr '|' '\n' | grep DNA
```

prints

```
AssistantDNA Property 
LabDNA
```

First replace the `|` with a new line, then use normal grep.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use an Extended Regular Expression

Assuming that your data is in a file named */tmp/foo*, you can use *egrep* or `grep -E` (depending on your system) to match just the words you want with an extended regular expression:

```
egrep --only-matching --ignore-case '\b[[:alnum:]]+dna\b' /tmp/foo | sort
```

The *sort* pipeline at the end will just sort the results alphabetically for you. It certainly isn't necessary, based on your stated requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -Po "\S*DNA\S*" yourFile
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "Properties | Account Property | Actions Property | Anniversary Property | Application Property | AssistantName Property | AssistantDNA Property | LabDNA...."|grep -Po "\S*DNA\S*"
AssistantDNA
LabDNA....
```